# All XP PCs suddenly can't access domain shares

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-xp, domain-controller, network-share

We have one shared folder on one of our domain controller server 2012R2. From yesterday, all our XP PCs suddenly couldn't access this domain share. All other Win 7, Win 8, Win 10 PCs have no such problem at all. We didnt have any changes on domain share and Domain controllers.

I can pin from xp to this DC and the name can be resolved both way. the share on this DC can't be reached by either IP or name.

I could not think of any cause to this issue.

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Windows update on the 2012-r2 enhanced share security ?

Comment: No updates applied lately.... All XP can access shares on other server, just can't access the share on one DC suddenly by name or IP. saying that "can't find \\dc2. check the spelling"

Comment: Open regedit on an affected server and look for the following key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\ look for the value of DependOnService what is it

Comment: The current vale is "SamSS Srv2"

Comment: I guess I have to change it to "SamSS Srv". but it was working before. There was no change at all on DC.

Comment: Thanks Drifter104    It worked after change the value and reboot